# Prepared statements getting ‘SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined’ PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am getting an "Invalid parameter" fault on two small tables after happily building three complicated ones. I realize this is a highly duplicated question. I have checked literally dozens of answers here and elsewhere online.

I have cut and pasted names from the DB just to make 100% sure I am not missing any typos. I have used case sensitive searches. I am not using any banned characters in place holders, I am not using any reserved words. I have triple and quadruple checked that the place holders match. I have `var_dump`ed and `echo`ed and all looks as it should be.

I have converted strings to integers although did not need to that in previous tables. I am sure this is simple but I have been stuck on this for about six hours and just cannot see where I am going wrong. As two simple tables are both having problems I restarted and rebooted but nothing. I must presume I am doing something stupid but I really cannot see it.

```
if ($_GET ['randomTime']== "yes") {

$sql = "INSERT INTO randomTime (
transmissionProgramID,
numberOfTimes,
minimumGap,
randomTimeType,
lastUpdate
) VALUES (
:transmissionProgramID,
:numberOfTimes,
:minimumGap,
:randomTimeType,
:lastUpdate
);";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$numberOfTimes = intval($numberOfTimes);
$minimumGap = intval($minimumGap);
$transmissionProgramID = intval($transmissionProgramID);

var_dump($transmissionProgramID,$numberOfTimes,$randomTimeType, $minimumGap,$lastUpdate);

$statement->bindValue(':transmissionProgramID,', $transmissionProgramID);
$statement->bindValue(':numberOfTimes,', $numberOfTimes);
$statement->bindValue(':minimumGap,', $minimumGap);
$statement->bindValue(':randomTimeType,', $randomTimeType);
$statement->bindValue(':lastUpdate', $lastUpdate);
$result = $statement->execute();

$randomTimeID = $pdo->lastInsertId();
}
```

The table is very straightforward

```
CREATE TABLE `randomTime` (
`randomTimeID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`numberOfTimes` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`minimumGap` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '60',
`randomTimeType` ENUM('average','fixed','maximum') NULL DEFAULT 'fixed',
`transmissionProgramID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`lastUpdate` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`randomTimeID`),
UNIQUE INDEX `randomTimeID` (`randomTimeID`),
INDEX `FK_randomTime_transmissionProgram` (`transmissionProgramID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_randomTime_transmissionProgram` FOREIGN KEY        
(`transmissionProgramID`) REFERENCES `transmissionProgram` (`transmissionProgramID`)
)
```

[image]

The var_dump produces what it should eg:

```
string(3) "131" string(1) "2" string(7) "average" int(200) string(19) "2016-03-01 14:36:42"
```

before I did `intval` on everything and now it shows

```
int(137) int(2) string(7) "average" int(60) string(19) "2016-03-01 17:33:32"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma isn't part of the named parameter. That separators the placeholders/values.

Your code should be:

```
$statement->bindValue(':transmissionProgramID', $transmissionProgramID);
$statement->bindValue(':numberOfTimes', $numberOfTimes);
$statement->bindValue(':minimumGap', $minimumGap);
$statement->bindValue(':randomTimeType', $randomTimeType);
$statement->bindValue(':lastUpdate', $lastUpdate);
```

Comment: Thank you. Oh **** well I suspect that will be the last question I will ever be allowed to ask.  Thank you very much can get on with the rest. EDIT with your permission I am going to delete this before it gets down voted

Comment: Mind you I think that will get me banned as well

Comment: Why would this question get you banned?

Comment: I am on the cusp of having asked too many dumb "I cannot see what is wrong" questions and have been 0 or minus rated for several. The system (not people) decides if you have been iunsufficiently helpful. Before I posted this I got THE WARNING and suspect I will be blocked as deleting post ALSO counts against you. I sometimes look and look and cannot see, People here judge that to be bad http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562407/undefined-variable-really-php-blindness eg.

Comment: So will delete becasue if I own up to it being a "typo" it will be down voted.

Comment: Thanks very very much for your help tho

Comment: Oh, didn't know there were those limits. You could also try answering some questions on the site. I imagine that would put you back on the helpful side.

Comment: LOL ROFLMAO I try oh how I try. Anything I can answer is answered in under 20 seconds - literally, I have written nice little answers but always get beaten to the punch and to be honest I am a Jack of All Trades and master of none... Just trying to build one rather complicated small web site. I tried just now and then realised the question made no sense,

Comment: OK gonna do it - hope this does not make matters worse.

Comment: Yea, there are a good amount of question that also make no sense. This question is better than those which is why I didn't know why you'd get banned.

Comment: I am just terrified the SO meanies will be along and down vote me - but as you seem to have given me a vote I will wait hopefully. Let's see what happens